# Limit program execution to a list of arguments

Tags: permissions, security, c, setuid, setgid

I would like that my Unix users can only run a specific command `insecurecommand` with a controlled list of arguments stored in a file.

The only solution I have found at this time is to :

1. Create a new security group called `cmdxg`
2. Limit the execution of the command to this group:

   ```
   chown root:cmdxg /.../insecurecommand
   chmod 750 /.../insecurecommand
   ```
3. Create a setgid wrapper, which executes the command:

   ```
   ls -al /.../mywrapper
   -rwxr-sr-x 1 root cmdxg /.../mywrapper
   ```

The only problem is that `insecurecommand` is executed with `gid=cmdxd` and not with the users real gid. However, I'd like to avoid running the `insecurecommand` command setgid.

If in the wrapper code, I go back to real gid with seteuid(), it can't run the `insecurecommand` anymore because the process lost the `cmdxg` right.

Is it a way to run a command that needs privileged gid rights, but with the real gid ?

Maybe I need to decompose the program execution ?

-> first load the binary with the privileged effective gid
-> go back to the real gid
-> run the program

But how can I do this ?

Any ideas ?

Comment: I don't follow "If in the wrapper, I go back to real gid I can't run the command anymore."

Comment: Could you not just use `sudo`?

Comment: @Warwick good point. if the poster is ok having the list of arguments in `/etc/sudoers` or similar.

Comment: Thank you for the sudo suggestion but I don't understand how to implement it. Sudo permit to execute a command as another user. As the `insecurecommand` can't be executed unprivileged, I need a special user for the `insecurecommand` sudo execution. But in this case the uid and gid are not set accordingly to the original user executing the command and this is problematic for the file created by the `insecurecommand` program.

Comment: i would recommend you to write a wrapper script which does filter the arguments allowd and then invoke the command it selfs. then just call the script like the actual command and add the path to it to the $PATH variable but make shure to place it before the path of the actual commands path.

Comment: That's what I did. But I need a method to prevent the user executing the command directly.

Comment: Combine the wrapper with `sudo`. So the wrapper collects the current UID and GID of the user running the script and the name of any file name to output to (Look up how to collect the parameters passed to a shell script if you do not already know this). Within the wrapper, call `sudo` to run the command, then finally `chown` the file to the original UID and GID.

Comment: seems you're on the right track, but you may want to read http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part4/section-7.html for some pitfalls on mixing setuid and shell scripts, just in case.